# Presto Window functions efficiency

Tags: window-functions, presto

I am encountering an issue that is related to Presto window functions. Whenever I run the window function I seem to run in to node emenory error(Query exceeded per-node total memory limit; Top Consumers: TopNRowNumberOperator ).

It seems to me like the window functions (EX: row_number() over ( partition by col order by coln ) execute on single node unlike aggregate functions which are distributed. Is there a way to make windowing functions distributed? If not, can I get list of things on Presto that won't be distributed. Any information on this is appreciated.

My presto version is 0.338

Thanks

Comment: `row_number() over ( partition by col order by coln )` is executed on multiple machines, partitioned by `col`. If will be single node if you have single value of `col` (or have very few values and there is hash collision)

Comment: If it is partitioned by multiple columns, does the order of columns give in partition by matters? (EX: partition by col1, col2 and col3 )